# XSS & SQLi Prevention + Getting variable from URL

Tags: php, get, key, xss

I would like to do API for thing I am working on but I can't figure out how to fix things that I have now.

I want to have something like login, if key is right and matching the IP in database then do other things

```
if (isset($_GET['key'])) {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    $apikey = $_GET['key'];
    //$apikey = mysql_real_escape_string($api);
    echo $apikey."<br />".$ip;

    $mysql_host = "**.***.**.***";
    $mysql_database = "*****";
    $mysql_user = "********";
    $mysql_password = "******************";

    mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
    @mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die("Unable to select database");
    $query="SELECT * FROM `api` WHERE `apikey` = '".$apikey."' AND `ip`='".$ip"'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }

    // assign mySQL values from table to php variables
    $teest = mysql_result($result,1,'apikey');
    echo $teest;
    //close the mySQL connection        
    mysql_close();
} else {
    echo "Usage: api.php?key={YourUniqueKey}";
}
```

Comment: Use `mysql_num_rows()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) the extension providing the mysql_* function is marked as deprecatd. Better use mysqli or [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo).

b) You're putting two parameters (as string literals) into your sql query. Both (string) parameters must be encoded/escaped properly so they cannot interfer with the actual query (structure).
This is done by mysql_real_escape_string. But this function needs some information from the connection resource (namely the connection charset) to work properly. Therefore you can make the call to mysql_real_escape_string() only after you've establied the mysql connection viw mysql_connect.

```
<?php
if ( !isset($_GET['key']) ) {
    echo "Usage: api.php?key={YourUniqueKey}";
}
else {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    $apikey = $_GET['key'];
    echo htmlspecialchars($apikey)."<br />".htmlspecialchars($ip);

    $mysql_host = "**.***.**.***";
    $mysql_database = "*****";
    $mysql_user = "********";
    $mysql_password = "******************";
    $link = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password) or die('database connection failed');
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $link) or die("Unable to select database");

    $query = sprintf(
        "
            SELECT
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                api
            WHERE
                apikey='%s'
                AND ip='%s'
        ", 
        mysql_real_escape_string($apikey, $link),
        mysql_real_escape_string($ip, $link)
    );
    $result=mysql_query($query, $link);
    if (!$result) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    if ( '1'==$row[0] ) {
        echo 'yay';
    }
    else {
        echo 'nay';
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Better use mysqli or PDO."* - The use of `mysqli_` and/or PDO are not safeguards against SQL injection; not on their own that is. Using [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or **PDO** with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) will. ;)

Comment: Doesn't work for me, says SQL Syntax error, my php version is "5.5.3"

Comment: Modified code a bit and it works, thank you very much :)